# Eclipse 4.2.2 on Fedora 18 open declaration not working

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, ide

I'm using Eclipse 4.2.2 on Fedora 18. For a C++ project , I execute the command `select a function > click on navigate > open declaration`, and `open declaration` is disabled...
I also tried clr+click and nothing happened.

How can I open the function's declaration?

Comment: have you set the include paths..etc correctly for the project?

Answer (score 3):

You may not have the source code for that function available, or the include paths may not tell Eclipse where the appropriate code is located. Did you write this function? Or where is this function coming from?

I am led to believe that you're probably using some 3rd party library without the source code being available to eclipse, and eclipse cannot just invent the declaration on its own.

Comment: In fact I'm very novice linux user, I have a folder containing all the sources and libraries which can be built without any error using command line. what I did is only create new c++ project in eclipse, then drag the code folder in the workspace ... maybe I need to do something else ? ...

Comment: so the function is declared in the code you put in the Eclipse project? and when you're in eclipse, you can see all of the code files that are in that folder? (I don't know if adding files to a folder is enough to add them to a project in Eclipse, and if they aren't in the project, then Eclipse won't know about them.) Eclipse is rather a pain to work with in my experience. Anjuta might be worth testing out, or something else. To be honest, all I normally use is Sublime Text and a terminal window when I'm developing code. IDEs can be nice sometimes.

Comment: yes the code is working , I build and run from terminal also, in plus eclipse  open declaration and definition was working when I was using another desktop...

Answer (score 0):

As coder543 has answered it may happen that you might not have source code available. I have experienced same problem and it may be because:
 1. If you are using #ifdef and other directives and if function is in portion that is disabled you wouldn't be able to see it. 
 2. If function has been commented it won't show with ctrl + Click.

Check for above two possibilities. 
For solution you should search function name as a text within project or workspace. Use "Search->Text" option for that.